# Logitech wired USB mouse acting strange on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mouse, logitech

I have a logitech wired USB mouse. I have been using this mouse on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop for a few months without any problem. A month ago, it started acting strange. Single click would sometimes register double click and left click would sometimes register right click. At first I thought its a problem with my mouse but then I tried the same in Windows 7 and it worked fine. Also, when I tried plugging it in to another USB port then also it worked fine. So I used it like that for a few more weeks. However, couple of days ago the same problem has appeared again. Now, I might try another USB port and it might work fine again. But what is the long term solution for this ?

Comment: This actually sounds like a hardware issue. Have you tried using it in Windows 7 for a couple days or so (sounds like you only tried it in Windows for a short period)? I somewhat doubt this is a driver issue.

Comment: Its not a hardware issue in the mouse. That I can confirm. I have used the mouse on another system for days without any issue

Comment: It still sounds like a hardware problem with the mouse, even though the mouse works elsewhere. Do you have another mouse to try?

Comment: no I don't. The mouse is under warranty though. But I read somewhere that logitech mice have some issues with Ubuntu